# Как на php из многомерного массива сделать одномерный с объединением значений вложенных массивов

Tags: php

Пожалуйста, помогите с php массивами.
Есть многомерный массив следующего вида:

```
Array
(
  [Apple] => Array
    (
        [0] => iPhone 5
        [1] => iPhone 6
        [2] => iPhone X
    )

  [Xiaomi] => Array
    (
        [0] => Redmi
        [1] => Mi
    )

  [Samsung] => Array
    (
        [0] => Galaxy
    )
)
```

как этот массив преобразовать в такой вид:

```
Array
(
  [Apple] => iPhone 5, iPhone 6, iPhone X
  [Xiaomi] => Redmi, Mi
  [Samsung] => Galaxy
)
```

Comment: пробежать циклом и сделать везде implode (https://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php)

Answer (score 2):

видимо так

```
$result = array_map(function($v){ 
                        return implode(',', $v);
                    }, $data);
```

зы: продолжение детективной истории в стиле гадания на кофейной гуще.

Если у вас массив вида

```
$data = [['iPhone5', 'apple'], ['iphone6', 'apple'], ['galaxy', 'samsung']];
```

то сначала сформируйте массив с ключами-брендами:

```
$brands = array_fill_keys(array_column($data, 1), []);
```

далее распихайте модели по этим брендам, либо просто циклом

```
foreach($data as list($model, $brand)){
    $brands[$brand][] = $model;
}
```

либо посложнее

```
 $result = array_reduce($data, function($c, $v){ $c[$v[1]][] = $v[0]; return $c; }, $brands);
```

в результате получите массив в том виде, как оно указано в вашем вопросе. После чего можете применить функцию, которая приведена в начале ответа.

Можете и без функции, сразу складывать не в массив, а формировать желаемую строку. Там просто запятую в начале/конце придется контролировать/убирать.

типа

```
foreach($data as list($model, $brand)){
    $b = &$brands[$brand];
    $b .= ($b ? ",": "") . $model;
}
```

Comment: попробовал и получилось вот так: 
Array
(
    [0] => iPhone 5,Apple
    [1] => iPhone 6,Apple
    [2] => iPhone 6s,Apple
    [3] => Redmi,Xiaomi
    [4] => Mi,Xiaomi
    [5] => Galaxy,Samsung
)
что отличается от того, что требуется

Comment: @teran вам дал правильный ответ. Если вывод неверный, то вы передаете входной массив  с другой структурой, чем та, что вы указали в вопросе.

Comment: @Иван чтобы получить такой вывод, как вы написали входной массив должен иметь вид `[['iPhone5', 'Apple'], ['iphone6', 'apple'], ...]`, а не тот, что у вас в вопросе.

Comment: @teran тогда вопрос как подогнать входной массив под такой вид? ну не моё этот php, а по работе понадобилось

Comment: @Иван для начала указать в вопросе верные входные данные =)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, но именно такие входные данные и получаются после парсинга html-таблицы

Comment: @Иван прочтите третий комментарий под этим ответом

Comment: @teran, огромное спасибо. Всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Перебрать ключи массива и для каждого изменить значение: массив значений превратить строку значений через запятую-пробел:

```
$arr = [
    'Apple' => ['iPhone 5', 'iPhone 6', 'iPhone X'],
    'Xiaomi' => ['Redmi', 'Mi'],
    'Samsung' => ['Galaxy'],
];
var_dump(array_map(function($row){return implode(', ', $row);}, $arr));
/* array(3) {
  ["Apple"]=>string(28) "iPhone 5, iPhone 6, iPhone X"
  ["Xiaomi"]=>string(9) "Redmi, Mi"
  ["Samsung"]=>string(6) "Galaxy"
} */
```

Comment: чем ваш ответ отличается от того, что был дан ранее?